# Closures in JavaScript: one more example

Tags: javascript

```
function say667() {
    console.log(1);
    // Local variable that ends up within closure
    var num = 666;
    var sayAlert = function() {
            console.log(num);
        }
    num++;
    return sayAlert;
}
say667();
```

Why doesn't this work? It consolelogs `1` but doesn't console.log `num`.

Comment: What is the question? You wonder why you don't get the `console.log(num)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't this work?

Because `say667()` does *return* the `sayAlert` function (the *closure*), it does not invoke it. Try

```
var say = say667(); // logs 1 and returns the function
say(); // logs 667
say(); // logs 667 again
```

Answer (score 4):

You're returning the actual function, you're not calling the function, you need to add () after "sayAlert"

```
function say667() {
    console.log(1);
    // Local variable that ends up within closure
    var num = 666;
    var sayAlert = function() {
            console.log(num);
        }
    num++;
    return sayAlert();
}
say667();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KbaZt/)

Comment: why do we need 'return'?

Comment: It's not necessary in this scenario. But clearly this isn't production code.  Rather than refactor, I just answered the question.

Comment: That somehow defeats the point of closure.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `return sayAlert;` you have to call `return sayAlert();`

```
(function() {
   console.log(1);
   // Local variable that ends up within closure
   var num = 666;
   var sayAlert = function() { console.log(num); }
   num++;
   return sayAlert();
})();
```

Here this function will call automatically.

Or with yours,

```
function say667() {
    console.log(1);
    // Local variable that ends up within closure
    var num = 666;
    var sayAlert = function() {
            console.log(num);
    }
    num++;
    return sayAlert();
}
say667();
```

Comment: That somehow defeats the point of the closure the OP wanted.

Comment: added note in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `say667()();` but that's not really good from a garbage-collector point of view. It's better to `return sayAlert()` from the say667-function.

Comment: Where would the difference be to the garbage collector?

Comment: Returning an object (return sayAlert) will keep that object in menory. If you instead return the result of the object (return sayAlert()) in the form om a numer or a string, then the sayAlert object can be disposed of instead of being kept in memory.

Comment: Well, if you return it but then invoke it instead of storing it in some variable (`say667()()`) I don't see why it would be kept in memory.